# dynamic style for google-chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically update the width and height of a google-chart directive using values from input fields. The width and height is not being updated.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g8iWSc?p=preview)

```
$scope.height = "300"
$scope.width = "300"
$scope.cssStyle = "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; height:" + $scope.width + "px";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chart.options` for updating google-chart property like `title`, `width`, `height` etc.

**By changing value of `chart.options` there is no need to change width and heigth of `div`.**

Use `ng-change` for updating value of `chat.options`

Update `input` element by adding `ng-change`

```
<input type="text" value="300px" ng-change="change()" ng-model="width"/>
<input type="text" value="300px" ng-change="change()" ng-model="height"/>
```

Add below `change()` function to controller

```
$scope.change = function() {
   $scope.chart.options = {
      height: $scope.width,
      width: $scope.height,
  };
}
```

Check updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBeC25Yo0DRtQJm4qsaF?p=preview)

Comment: Oh, neat. I never used `google-chart`. It's good to know those options are available.

Comment: @SarjanDesai Works Perfectly for me...done minor tweaks as i need to run it on SharePoint 2013..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Typo in 3rd line?

```
$scope.cssStyle = "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; height:" + $scope.width + "px";
```

to be

```
$scope.cssStyle = "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; width:" + $scope.width + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the style declaration:

```
//"height:" + $scope.height+ "px; height:" + $scope.width + "px";
  "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; width:" + $scope.width + "px";
```

`$scope.cssStyle` won't be continually updated as `$scope.height` and `$scope.width` change. To fix that, you can turn `$scope.cssStyle` into a function that returns the calculation.

```
<div google-chart chart="chart" style="{{cssStyle()}}"/>
```

```
$scope.cssStyle = function() {
  return "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; width:" + $scope.width + "px";
};
```

With that, the `cssStyle` is updating as you desire, but the `google-chart` directive doesn't seem to update with the new parameters. You can hack around that by removing it from the DOM and re-adding it.

```
<div ng-if="on" google-chart chart="chart" style="{{cssStyle}}"/>
```

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  // watch this for changes
  return "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; width:" + $scope.width + "px";
}, function(style) {
  // there is a new style
  $scope.on = false; // remove chart
  $timeout(function() {
    // trigger another digest cycle to add chart with new style
    $scope.cssStyle = style;
    $scope.on = true;
  });
});
```

[**Click here for live demo.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rEQo8YUpdGnsNrC38brw?p=preview)

Credit to Sarjan's answer - he found the best way to update the `google-chart` dimensions is by using the `options` property of the `chart` object. The directive watches that object and responds to changes.

Answer (score -1):

Basically what is happening is you cssStyle property is one way binding so what you need to do is you need to calculate the css style property on width or height property as following:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(["width", "height"], function(newValues, oldValues){
    $scope.cssStyle = "height:" + $scope.height+ "px; width:" + $scope.width + "px";
  })
```

**Note: Upgarde your angular to 1.3.0** then you will get the `$watchGroup` method for scope.
Check the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WEe3rPzapIBz3uhoGabI?p=preview